# apply template in xslt not working as expected

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Below are input output xml along with xslt and expected result

**Input xml-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
        <name>Cat</name>
        <sal>1</sal>
</data>
```

**xslt with template:-**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Details>
            <EmployeeName>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>
             </EmployeeName>    
        </Details>
    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="employee">
<TEST>
 <xsl:value-of select="'CAT'"/>
</TEST>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output getting:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Details><EmployeeName/></Details>
```

**Expected output:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details>
<EmployeeName>
<TEST>CAT</TEST>
</EmployeeName>
</Details>
```

Comment: I don't get why you are trying to match an `<employee>` element which isn't even present in your XML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only apply templates to nodes that exist but `<xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>` doesn't select anything in your input sample.